# Lock reading/writing for rows in two dimension array in global memory

Tags: arrays, cuda, locking, gpu

I have two dimensional array and there are threads which update rows in the array. May be two or more threads need to update one row at a time. I need to lock threads which are trying to access same row if there is a thread updating it.

Answer (score 1):

If your threads only need to update one element in the row then a simple atomic operation (e.g. `atomicAdd()`) should do it.

If related operations must be performed on multiple elements of the row, you need to implement some sort of "critical section" control. For example:

```
#define ROW_COUNT 10

__global__
void the_kernel( ... ) {
    // block-level shared array indicating the locking state of each row
    __shared__ int locks[ ROW_COUNT ];

    // initialize shared array
    if ( threadIdx.x == 0 ) memset( locks, 0, sizeof( int ) * ROW_COUNT );
    __syncthreads();

    // suppose the current thread need to update row #3
    int row_idx = 3;

    // thread-local variable indicating whether current thread has access to the target row
    bool updating = false;
    do {
        // return value from atomicCAS will be 0 when no other thread is updating row #3
        // otherwise current thread should loop until the row lock is released by other threads
        updating = (atomicCAS( locks + row_idx, 0, -1 ) == 0);
        if (updating) {
            // entered critical section, do the work!

            // before we release the lock, we should make the changes made by current thread visible to other threads
            // we can not use __syncthreads() as this is inside a conditional branch, so we have to use __threadfence()
            __threadfence();

            // now releasing the lock
            atomicExch( locks + row_idx, 0 );
        }
    } while ( !updating );
}
```

That being said, this design is essentially serial that all but one thread updating the row will loop and wait for their turn. There will be performance penalties so use it only when absolutely necessary.

Please also note that the structure only works when all threads can fit into a single block (e.g. total of 1024 threads) because the shared memory array locking does not work across blocks. On GPUs with multiple SMs (i.e. multiple blocks can be scheduled on different SMs) it is very likely that threads from different blocks will try to access the rows in a race.